Android: Two Horizontal Side by Side Textview not managing the same height
I'm encountering a problem with TextView height adjustment in my Android application. When I select a quantity of one, only "Tamara" is displayed and the view appears correctly. However, when I change the quantity to three, both "Tabby" and "Tamara" are enabled and displayed perfectly. The issue arises when I change the quantity back to one; the height seems to be based on the previous selection when both "Tabby" and "Tamara" were visible.
fun adjust() {
    // Check if both views are visible
    val bothViewsVisible = binding.tabbyFrameLayout.isVisible && binding.tamaraFrameLayout.isVisible

    if (bothViewsVisible) {
        binding.tamaraMessageTv.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                // Remove the listener to avoid multiple calls
                binding.tamaraMessageTv.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                // Measure the height of both TextViews
                val height1 = binding.tamaraMessageTv.height
                val height2 = binding.tabbyMessageTv.height

                // Get the maximum height of both TextViews
                val maxHeight = max(height1, height2)

                // Set the height of both TextViews to the maximum height
                binding.tabbyMessageTv.height = maxHeight
                binding.tamaraMessageTv.height = maxHeight
            }
        })
    } else {
        binding.buyNowPayLaterContainer.requestLayout()
        Log.d("", "layoutHeight:: ${binding.tamaraMessageTv.height}")
    }
}

Here is the XML layout
`

<data>

</data>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/buyNowPayLaterContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabbyFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_border_grey"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/tabbyArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_with_padding" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
                style="@style/Italian_plate_no2_expanded_very_dark_grey_10sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tabbyArrow"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx, Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_tabby" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_65dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tamaraFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_tamara_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/tamaraArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_with_padding" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
                style="@style/Italian_plate_no2_expanded_very_dark_grey_10sp"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tamaraArrow"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:id="@+id/tamaraImageView"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tamara_icon" />

    </FrameLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

`
How can I ensure that the TextView height adjusts dynamically based on the quantity selected, so that only the necessary TextViews are visible without any excess space when the quantity changes?
Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!
I've attempted various approaches both in the code and XML layouts, but none have resolved the issue.
Could someone offer guidance or suggest a solution to ensure that the TextView height adjusts dynamically based on the quantity selected, displaying only the necessary TextViews without any extra space when the quantity changes?

It's not clear in your code and layout which quantity did you refer to

You can always calculate the size manually and than update the size by using the right events.
Here is an example I used when I had a similar issue:

I already added the code for manual setting the height still I am getting the prev height

Initial Quantity is 1: Showing properly,
change quantity to 2: Showing properly -> Height increase
Change quantity to 1: Not Showing properly -> It is taking the height of second step (Unexpected)


Have you tried setting maxHeight to the desired height you want?

You need to use the layoutParams to set the heights of the views which is more flexible and better integration than setting out the height directly.
I guess the viewTreeObserver is also not required so removed that part.
Also, don't forget to call the invalidate() before calling the requestLayout() as sometimes calling the requestLayout() is not guarenteed in onDraw() phase of the view.
Sample Code is below:
private fun adjustHeights() {
        val bothViewsVisible =
            binding.tabbyFrameLayout.isVisible && binding.tamaraFrameLayout.isVisible

        if (bothViewsVisible) {
            // Measure the height of both TextViews
            val height1 = binding.tamaraMessageTv.height
            val height2 = binding.tabbyMessageTv.height

            // Get the maximum height of both TextViews
            val maxHeight = max(height1, height2)

            // Set the height of both TextViews to the maximum height
            binding.tabbyMessageTv.layoutParams.height = maxHeight
            binding.tamaraMessageTv.layoutParams.height = maxHeight

            Log.d("test", "onGlobalLayout: ")
            Log.d("test", " Tabby layoutHeight:: ${binding.tabbyMessageTv.height}")
            Log.d("test", "Tamara layoutHeight:: ${binding.tamaraMessageTv.height}")
        } else if (binding.tabbyFrameLayout.isVisible) {
            binding.tabbyMessageTv.layoutParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT
            Log.d("test", "Tabby Visible: ")

            Log.d("test", " Tabby layoutHeight:: ${binding.tabbyMessageTv.height}")
        } else {
            binding.tamaraMessageTv.layoutParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT
            Log.d("test", "Tamara Visible: ")

            Log.d("test", "Tamara layoutHeight:: ${binding.tamaraMessageTv.height}")
        }
        binding.buyNowPayLaterContainer.invalidate()
        binding.buyNowPayLaterContainer.requestLayout()
    }

For the xml layout part,
keep wrap_content for the frame layout height in both of the views.
<FrameLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...>
     ...
</FrameLayout>



<FrameLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...>
    ...
</FrameLayout>


It's not clear to me how your layout needs to look like, but i think you've implemented it in a complex way, which is in my opinion not necessary to achieve what i think you're layout needs to look like.
Try this simplified version of your layout, using it both textviews will always be centered vertically with no need to add any observers in code.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/middle_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabbyBg"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tabbyMessageTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_tabby" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabbyArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/middle_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_with_padding" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabbyMessageTv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tabbyArrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabbyBg"
        tools:text="Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx, Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx"/>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/tamaraArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_with_padding" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tamaraMessageTv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tamaraArrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/middle_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tamaraImageView"
        tools:text="Pay 4 interest-free payments of AED xx.xx"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tamaraImageView"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tamaraMessageTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tamara_icon" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

